# error RC2175 : resource file res\icon3.bmp is not in 3.00 format?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005, image-formats

HI,

what does this mean, and how to resolve it?

error RC2175 : resource file res\icon3.bmp is not in 3.00 format

Comment: I think it probably means that your `res\icon3.bmp` file is in the wrong format. My psychic debugging skills tell me that it should probably be upgraded to the 3.00 format. I could be wrong.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Seeing as Visual Studio is getting somewhat antiquated, I'd think the file should be **downgraded** to the 3.00 format.  Otherwise I completely concur with your assessment.

Comment: If you have imagemagick at hand, just `convert icon3.bmp icon3.ico` should give you the correct format. Easiest way to get imagemagick on Windows 10 is to use `apt-get install imagemagick` in WSL, if you already enabled that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your .bmp file is corrupted or using a compression format not supported by vs2005.  Trying opening it in another program, such as mspaint, and then save as uncompressed bmp.

Answer (score 0):

Go to that line of code, change BITMAP to PNG and that should solve the problem if you want to use .png image

Comment: I ran into this problem.  Changing the .rc line as directed in this solution got rid of the error (which doesn't mean it's the best or only solution).